# Value of optional type 'UITextField?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'text' of wrapped base type 'UITextField'

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a textfield to search the value in the array. But I get an error like this.
What should we do to convert the data type? I am using Swift 5.

**Value of optional type 'UITextField?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'text' of wrapped base type 'UITextField'**

```
    for i in 0..<allUser.count {
        if allUser[i].name.contains(textArea.text) { // here is the error
            print(allUser[i].name)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you unwrap the object before the loop `if let text = textArea?.text {` and the use `text` in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

The error you were getting is because textArea is optional and textArea.text returns an optional string, and the 'contains' function expects a non-optional string.

First, unwrap the text, then loop over the filtered matches and print these.

```
if let text = textArea?.text {
   for user in allUser.filter({ $0.name.contains(text) }) {
      print(user.name)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should safely unwrap the text using `if-let` statement.

```
for i in 0..<allUser.count{
    if let textValue = textArea.text {
        if allUser[i].name.contains(textValue){
            print(allUser[i].name)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is about the **text field**, not the `text` property.

You can even write

```
if let textField = textArea {
   let text = textField.text!
   for user in allUser where user.name.contains(text) {
      print(user.name)
   }
}
```

because the `text` property of an `UITextField` won’t be `nil`, however in this case this is preferable

```
if let text = textArea?.text {
   for user in allUser where user.name.contains(text) {
      print(user.name)
   }
}
```